# Linear Algebra Orthogonality: Finding orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-polynomials

I have this question on an assignment, and I live off-campus and office hours are hard to go to.

I was able to complete part (a), by showing that the inner product of the 2 vectors is equal to 0. For part (b) I have no idea what to do. I know that the standard basis for $P_2(R)$ are $\{1,x,x^2\}$ but how do I come up with an orthogonal basis that contains $S$?

[image]

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: Thanks, I have some knowledge of the GS process and thought it was to come up with an orthonormal basis, but I do remember now that in the process it first reaches an orthogonal basis. Many thanks, the topic hasn't been taught by our Prof yet.

Comment: Actually if I do Gram-Schmidt on S, I get back S because <x^2 - 1, x^2 - 100> = 0 because as shown in part a), S is already an orthogonal set.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani didnt tag you above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $S$ is orthogonal we need to find a vector that is orthogonal to $S$ since the dimension of $P_2(R)$ is three.  Starting with $ax^2+bx+c$ ends in $-10x^2+99x+10$.

Comment: but $\langle x^2-100, x-10\rangle=0$ isn't true.

Comment: I've corrected my attempt.